# Pct_change in python with missing data

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have quarterly time series data that I am calculating derivatives for. The problem is, the raw data has gaps in the time series. Therefore, if I am trying to find the quarter-over-quarter percent change in a variable, there are times when it will not realize it's calculating a percent change for a period much longer than a quarter. How do I make sure the pct_change() is only being done if the preceding data point is from the previous quarter (not further back)

Related to this, I am looking to calculate Year-over-year percent changes, which would have to go back 4 periods. I could use pct_change and just have it look back 4 periods rather than 1, but again, that assumes all the data is present.

What would be the best approach for handling this situation?

Below is the code I would use if the data was perfect:

```
dataRGQoQ = rawdata.groupby("ticker")['revenueusd'].pct_change()
```

I have included sample data below. There are 2 points in this data to focus on: (1) with ticker 'A', the gap between '2006-09-30' and '2007-12-31'; and (2) with ABV the gap (this time is slightly different because it has the dates and no data) between '2012-12-31' and '2013-12-31'.

```
ticker,calendardate,revenueusd  
A,2005-12-31,5139000000  
A,2006-03-31,4817000000  
A,2006-06-30,4560000000  
A,2006-09-30,4325000000  
A,2007-12-31,5420000000  
A,2008-03-31,5533000000  
A,2008-06-30,5669000000  
A,2008-09-30,5739000000  
AA,2005-12-31,26159000000  
AA,2006-03-31,27242000000  
AA,2006-06-30,28438000000  
AA,2006-09-30,29503000000  
AA,2006-12-31,30379000000  
AA,2007-03-31,31338000000  
AA,2007-06-30,31445000000  
AA,2007-09-30,31201000000  
AA,2007-12-31,30748000000  
ABBV,2012-12-31,18380000000  
ABBV,2013-03-31,  
ABBV,2013-06-30,      
ABBV,2013-09-30,      
ABBV,2013-12-31,18790000000  
ABBV,2014-03-31,19024000000  
ABBV,2014-06-30,19258000000  
ABBV,2014-09-30,19619000000  
ABBV,2014-12-31,19960000000  
ABBV,2015-03-31,20437000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to put `['calendardate', 'ticker']` in the index to facilitate pivoting.  Then `unstack` to get ticker values in the columns.

```
df.set_index(['calendardate', 'ticker']).unstack().head(10)
```

[image]

With `calendardate` in the index, we can use `resample('Q')` to insert all quarters.  This will ensure we get the proper `NaN`'s for missing quarters.

```
df.set_index(['calendardate', 'ticker']).unstack().resample('Q').mean().head(10)
```

Assign this to `df1` and then we can do `pct_change`, `stack` back and `reset_index` to get columns back in the dataframe proper.

```
df1 = df.set_index(['calendardate', 'ticker']).unstack().resample('Q').mean()
df1.pct_change().stack().reset_index()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This helps with part of it. It fills the empty spaces although when it turns it to percent, the ABBV '2012-12-31' percent becomes -91%. Not sure why that is happening. Also, it doesn't address the first problem of the series for the ticker 'A' that has a gap between the dates '2006-09-30' and '2007-12-31'. Any thoughts on those 2 things?

Comment: you can remove the `limit=4`.  Question for you is, what do you want it to do?  Do you want `0%` for those quarters.  I'd fall on the side of leaving them `NaN`

Comment: Yes leave them as NaN

Comment: And then the most important thing is for the series around the ticker 'A'. I need the pct_change() to not just assume the data point ahead of it is the quarter before. Notice in the series for ticker 'A' there is a jump in the data but it does not even contain rows for the missing dates, thus, pct_change just assumes the data point before is a perfect continuation, when it reality it isn't. Any thoughts on how to take care of this?

Comment: thanks so much! This was very helpful! The only thing I added was during the stack/unstack was to set the dropna=False. That allowed me to not have the '2007-12-31' percent change for ticker 'A' be 25%. I didn't want my data analysis to think it had an amazing quarter when in reality that was a jump of over a year. Wouldn't have been able to figure this out without your help!